# mysql docker container won't run

Tags: linux, docker

I apologize if this has been asked before but I am having trouble running a mysql container in docker.  When I try running the container I get the errors shown below:

```
[xxxxxxx ~]$ sudo docker start -a mysql
2022-09-29 00:37:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-09-29 00:37:46+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-09-29 00:37:46+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-09-29 00:37:46+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
    You need to specify one of the following:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
    - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

I have been looking at documentation and done web searches but I'm still not sure how to set these variables if the container won't run.  It looks like best practice is to use random root password correct?

Any help you guys can provide would be greatly appreciated.  I'm pretty new to Linux and very new to Docker, and I'm trying to set up a Linux server for a CAD application we need to run.

Thanks!

Comment: [The docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) include simple examples.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide additional parameters (as environmental variables).

```
docker run 
--detach 
--name=server
--env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" 
--publish 3306:3306 
mysql
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful.  Using docker run --help explained those options for me.  So I ran docker run with those options and I get "Unable to find image 'mysql:latest' locally".  I guess I need the full path for mysql here?

Comment: It should download that automatically, from hub.docker.com (it is an official image) (you can explicitly download, with `docker pull mysql`)

Comment: The challenge I'm running into is that this server is on the cloud and is air gapped.  There is no access to the internet.  Is there any way to download specific repositories and install locally?  I created this docker container by installing docker on a centos virtual box machine on my home computer.  I then installed docker manually with a binary file on my server, then transferred the image to the server with a secure USB.

Comment: I see, this should be a different question, but you can do it with commands: (docker pull on your local host) after `docker save yourrepo/image > ./image.tar`, transfer the tar to the airgapped system, there docker load < ./image.tar and from here everything is the same as you were in your local env

Comment: This is where the confusion sinks in.  I did create an image, then loaded it.  I see three images and three containers if I query docker, which is correct.  If i run "docker info" it recognizes the three containers.  But if I try running the one above,       I get the unable to find the mysql image.  I assume I have to resolve the error I originally posted about docker start and mysql, but I can't use the run command to get there.  I hope I'm making sense.                   
  Server:
 Containers: 3
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 2
 Images: 3

Comment: Ok, I got it, my syntax was off on my run command!!! Dummy that I am.  I took a breath and looked at what you gave me, fixed a few things and I have a working container!!! thanks my friend!  The dreaded "Exited" status is gone.